# SQL inner join if not found omit condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

SQL inner join if not found omit condition

Suppose I have a SQL query like:

```
SELECT A.* FROM Table_A A
INNER JOIN Table_B B ON A.Field1 = B.Field1 AND A.Field2 = B.Field2
WHERE A.Field3 > 10
```

What I'd like to achieve is, we first inner join by `Field1`/`Field2`, if no data found only join by Field1.

What's the proper way to this?

Table A:

```
Id Field1 Field2 Field3
1  a      b      12
2  a      c      13
3  e      f      14
2  d      c      15
```

Table B:

```
Id Field1 Field2
1  a      b      
2  e      g
```

Result should be:

```
Id Field1 Field2 Field3
1  a      b      12
3  e      f      14
```

Comment: we first inner join by Field1/Field2, if no data found only join by Field1.??
Can you explain in detail?

Comment: Sure. If join A and B by `Field1` and `Field2` we found one data, then it's OK. But sometimes it may not meet both conditions together. In this case, we only want to join again only with `Field1` condition.

Comment: 1st join with Condition
INNER JOIN Table_B B ON A.Field1 = B.Field1 AND A.Field2 = B.Field2
If no data returns join by the condition with only
INNER JOIN Table_B B ON A.Field1 = B.Field1
Is this correct?

Comment: I'd try a union.  See below.

Comment: A reason for your trouble might be a suboptimal table design. Have you considered changing Table B to have one column with all values from Field1 and Field2 and a second column called type with values "1" or "2"?

Answer (score 1):

First part of the union is your original.  Second part joins only on the first set of fields in cases where there is no match for both sets of fields.

```
SELECT * FROM Table_A A
INNER JOIN Table_B B ON A.Field1 = B.Field1 AND A.Field2 = B.Field2
WHERE A.Field3 > 10

UNION

SELECT * FROM Table_A A
INNER JOIN Table_B B ON A.Field1 = B.Field1
WHERE A.Field3 > 10
  AND NOT EXISTS
     (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE_B B2
       WHERE A.Field1 = B2.Field1 AND A.Field2 = B2.Field2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join on the same table twice, one with inner join and one with left join and put the conditional logic on the left join.

```
select distinct t1.*
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t1.f2 = t2.f2
inner join table2 t3 on t1.f1 = t3.f1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;With Tab1(Id,Field1, Field2, Field3)
AS
(
SELECT 1,'a','b',12 Union all
SELECT 2,'a','c',13 Union all
SELECT 3,'e','f',14 Union all
SELECT 2,'d','c',15
)
,Tab2 (Id, Field1, Field2)
AS
(
SELECT 1,'a','b' Union ALL      
SELECT 2,'e','g' 
)
SELECT Id,Field1, Field2, Field3 From Tab1  
EXCEPT
SELECT Id
    ,Field1
    ,Field2
    ,Field3
FROM (
    SELECT I.Id
        ,i.Field1
        ,i.Field2
        ,i.Field3
        ,COUNT(i.Id) OVER (
            PARTITION BY i.Id ,i.Field1, i.Field2 ORDER BY i.Id
            ) Seq
    FROM Tab1 i
    LEFT JOIN Tab2 o ON i.Id = o.Id
     WHERE i.Field1 !=o.Field1 AND i.Field2 !=o.Field2
    ) Dt

WHERE Dt.Seq = 1 AND Dt.Field3 > 10
```

OutPut

```
Id  Field1  Field2  Field3
---------------------------
1    a       b       12
3    e       f       14
```

Comment: Your solution is quite rely on `Id`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CASE in INNER JOIN. Just check this :

```
declare @a table (col1 int, col2 int, col3 int)
declare @b table (col1 int, col2 int, col3 int)

Insert into @a values(1,1,11),(2,2,15),(3,4,20),(4,5,9)
Insert into @b values(1,1,5),(2,2,2),(3,3,20),(4,5,20)


select A.* from @a A inner join @b B on 
(CASE 
 WHEN  A.col2 = B.col2 then 1
 WHEN  A.col2 <> B.col2 then 1
 ELSE 1
END) = 1 and A.col1 = B.col1
where A.col3 > 10
```

Comment: Try prepare table @a with data like `Insert into @a values(1,1,11),(2,2,15),(3,3, 19),(3,4,20),(4,5,9)`. What I want to achieve is first with two conditions, if fails with only one. Your code seems we are not requiring second condition for me.

Comment: @JerryBian: Yes, It is same as you are expecting. If second condition fails I am returning 1 in my case condition which will still return the result as per your expectation

Comment: Did you mean `ELSE 0` ?

Comment: If I change my code "WHEN  A.col2 <> B.col2 then 1" to "WHEN  A.col2 <> B.col2 then 0" then result will be only those records where both col1 and col2 matches.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following query:

```
SELECT ta.*
FROM @Table_A ta 
INNER JOIN @Table_B tb ON ta.Field1 = tb.Field1
WHERE ta.Field3 > 10
AND 
(
   ta.Field2 = tb.Field2
   OR
   NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT 1 FROM @Table_A ta2
                INNER JOIN @Table_B tb2 ON ta2.Field1 = tb2.Field1 AND ta2.Field2 = tb2.Field2
                WHERE ta2.Field1 = ta.Field1
            )    
)
```

Demo link: http://rextester.com/DKRG30176